# amazon beanstalk ec2 instance current git sha

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I get current git sha of the commit that was `git aws.push` ?
My container_commands need to download a file on a server that has that head git sha as the file name so I need a way to determine it.

I've been browsing around `/opt/elasticbanstalk/` and  found file
`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/appsourceurl` which contains

```
"url": "https://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-43434324.s3.amazonaws.com/resources%2Fenvironments%2Dg-fea2ffeaf5%2F_runtime%2F_versions%2Fbb-test-eb%2Fgit-6cb3416a7a5a84ce864dd0213236984age4b0b9-2678564154681?Expires=1417813357&AWSAccessKeyId=-----&Signature=-----"
```

I could parse this and extract the git-sha the problem this git sha is different from my git head sha on local that I just git aws.pushed! Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can confirm version label (aka git commit) with [AWS Elastic Beanstalk API Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/CLIReference-cmd-DescribeApplications.html):

```
$ elastic-beanstalk-describe-applications
ApplicationName | ConfigurationTemplates | DateCreated | DateUpdated | Description | Versions
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
angrywhopper |  | 2013-12-05 10:44:21 -0800 | 2013-12-05 10:44:21 -0800 | N/A | git-c069d943a152871a3a43898ce19ea20295b1307d-1386466726575
```

It should match your local commit:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
c069d943a152871a3a43898ce19ea20295b1307d
```

Also, look for archive operation in the log:

```
2013-12-08 03:51:31,830 [INFO] (10377 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: Archive:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
c069d943a152871a3a43898ce19ea20295b1307d
   creating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/.ebextensions/
   ...
```

Comment: Hi Andrey thanks! I'm getting command not found with elastic-beanstalk-describe-applications. Do i need to set it up somewhow?

Comment: Hi! Yes, you will need to set it up: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/usingCLI.html

Comment: If I go in the amazon beanstalk online system and select a previous git sha to deploy, won't this give me the wrong sha (i.e. the latest one and not the one I asked to deploy)?

Comment: @user391986 It seems counterintuitive to me. If you pick another commit to deploy, then that commit should be reported in the deployment log. Do you see it differently? I will try to run the scenario later today.